# Firebird - Внутренняя процедура, условие с условием для цикла

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase, процедуры

Есть внутрення рабочая процедура

```
create or alter procedure SP_SEL_COST_FOR_DEVICE (
    IN_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE integer,
    IN_PROPOSAL_ID integer)
returns (
    OUT_DEVICES_ID integer,
    OUT_COUNT_HOUR numeric(15,2))
as
declare variable VAR_COUNT_HOUR numeric(15,2);
declare variable VAR_SORT_WORK_ID integer;
declare variable VAR_DEVICES_CL_ID integer;
declare variable VAR_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE integer;
declare variable VAR_DEVICE_ID integer;
begin
  for
    select d.SORT_WORK_ID, dp.DEVICE_ID, dp.DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, dp.DEVICES_CL_ID
      from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL dp
      join DEVICES d on d.ID = dp.DEVICE_ID
        where dp.PROPOSAL_ID = :IN_PROPOSAL_ID
          into :VAR_SORT_WORK_ID, :VAR_DEVICE_ID, :VAR_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE, :VAR_DEVICES_CL_ID do
  begin
….
```

Рабочая, все нормально.

Вопрос:
Можно каким-нибудь образом сделать, если в передаче «*IN_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE*» не пустое значение, то блок «*where*» (в *for*), выглядел бы так:

```
where dp.PROPOSAL_ID = :IN_PROPOSAL_ID and DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE = : IN_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE
```

**Очень не хотелось писать 2 одинаковых цикла.**

Comment: *Очень не хотелось писать 2 одинаковых цикла.* Думаю, Вам следует определиться с приоритетами. Эффективность кода или количество использованных байтов?

Comment: @Akina, дублирование кода - это еще и проблемы сопровождения.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Ну я не сказал, что привёл исчерпывающий список факторов... а вот ориентироваться на капризное "мне не хочется" нельзя ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Comment: @Akina, "мне не хочется", в некоторых случаях, может означать "я знаю, что это плохое решение, но не могу с ходу ответить почему именно".

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю FireBird, но обычно это делается так

```
where dp.PROPOSAL_ID = :IN_PROPOSAL_ID 
and (DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE = :IN_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE 
     or :IN_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE is null)
```

Но если FireBird не сможет это соптимизировать нормально, то можно получить потенциально узкое место по производительности.

Comment: Худший вариант тут, что обе ветки будут работать со скоростью оригинального запроса (без отсева по :IN_DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE)

Answer (score 0):

Если вариант, предложенный 4per, окажется слишком медленным (что маловероятно), то есть еще вариант FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT … с динамически собранным запросом. Но это крайний способ, использовать только когда проблемы производительности перекрывают проблемы сопровождения.